# WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, boot

I tried to follow this tutorial, and at some point I have to register the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }


}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.learn2code.vehicle.api.search.config.AppConfig]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:524) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:497) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:415) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:768) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at com.learn2code.vehicle.api.search.VehicleSearchApplication.main(VehicleSearchApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:215) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M1.jar:3.2.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:923) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:514) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M3.jar:6.1.0-M3]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

I think this is because the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class, can somebody help me out, please?
Also, pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-M1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.learn2code.vehicle.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>vehicle-search</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vehicle-search</name>
    <description>Vehcle search api project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Sorry for the long post. Essentialy, I'm just getting "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class cannot be opened because it does not exist", because(I think) of that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

I tried to add various dependencies, in pom.xml, but with no success

Answer (score 0):

`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` this class is deprecated in recent version of `spring-boot`,if you are trying to implement spring security with endpoint,you can achieve it through `SecurityFilterChain` class.

You dont have to extend your class to any predefined class.

You can simply annotate yourClass as `@Configuration`

For example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfigurer {

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore("yourFilterClass, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about this line? auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService); Where should I translate it? Configure method doesn't have AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter